# How to get all the hplugins for Gedit on Mac OSX 10.6.8

Tags: macos, osx-snow-leopard, gedit, gedit-plugin

I've recently installed gedit on my macbook (os 10.6.8) , and I have managed to  install a lot of really cool plugins that enhance it greatly. However when I look at the available list of plugins on the gedit site a lot of the plugins listed are not available to me on my macbook.

Is there an issue with compatibility etc , also does anybody know of a site that lists all the available plugins for gedit that work with mac osx and how to install them on a mac?